# Error:Failed to find target with hash string 'android-22' -in SDK directory

Tags: android, git, android-sdk-tools

I cloned a git project & I cant gradle sync the project. 
I know a lot of problems alike were discussed over stackoverflow but i tried almost every solution out there, but no help. What I did

- updated SDK Tools (Now 25.1.7) Platform version - API 24 revision 2
- updated gradle plugin upto 2.14.1

my app:build.gradle looks like below

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
             applicationId "bd.com.myapp"
             minSdkVersion 15
             targetSdkVersion 23
             versionCode 1
             versionName "1.0"
             multiDexEnabled true
         }
      }
```

I have some library sdks used in my project. But their required sdks are quite different, I figured that's not the issue. If I make their sdk same as the app then the same problem with the same title shows but the location of the problem shows in bintray.gradle in the volley library in this line

classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))

I also tried the opposite, making the app compile older sdk like the llibraries but no help.

I am stuck for a day please help me out.